# I made a sort after a count with mongoengine but it has very low efficiency,what can i do in this process?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

This is my code below

```
sorted(Db.objects.distinct('CompanyId'), key=lambda s: Db.objects(CompanyId=s).count())[-10:]
```

1,I made a count of a distinct field(CompanyId);

2,I made a sort of it above;

3,then i take 10 of the sorted count list.

This code takes too many times that i can not accept,what should i know?
Do i need a index in mongodb?

need help!

Comment: An index will help but this kind of thing should be performed with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) for performance.

Comment: @SteveRossiter thanks, first time met mongodb.:)

Comment: no problem, as ever it is valuable in the long term (although a bit boring in the short term) to read through the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, you should use aggregation for this.

Mongoengine provides [aggregation methods](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html).

You may try this:

```python
from operator import itemgetter
companies = Db.objects.item_frequencies('CompanyId', normalize=True)
top_companies = sorted(companies.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]
```

(This is untested and inspired from you question and the item_frequencies example in the docs. Anyway, as also said in comments, reading both MongoDB and MongoEngine docs can't hurt.)